# Find an element of a Finite Group based on a table of characters

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, characters

Given $G$ is a group of order 24 with the following table of characters

[image: Table of Characters for group G]

Find the value for element A.

These are all the instructions that are given. I guess I am not really getting this question. First I am assuming (without loss of generality) the G is an additive group
, where the identity element is $0$ and the inverse of any $B \in G$ is $-B$. And I proceed as follows.

$$X_5 + C_3 = A \implies -C_3 - X_5 = -A$$

Since $X_5 + C_5 = 1$, and $X_4+C_5=1 \implies -C_5-X_4 = -1$

, then I can then write
$$-C_3 - X_5 + X_5 + C_5 -C_5-X_4= -A + 1 - 1$$
$$\implies -C_3 - X_4 = -A \implies X_4 + C_3 = A = -1$$

However, to check the calculation I try using different elements, and I get a different conclusion. For example

$$X_5 + C_2 = -1 \implies -C_2 -X_5 = 1,\ \text{and}\ X_2 + C_2 = -1$$
and so 
$$X_2 + C_2 - C_2 - X_5 + X_5 + C_3 = -1 + 1 + A$$
$$\implies X_2 + C_3 = A = 1$$

So like I said it seems I am missing something very important here.

Comment: Note that $\chi_2\chi_4$ is an irreducible character of degree $3$ not equal to $\chi_4$.

Comment: Watch out! You are looking at a *character* table not a Cayley table! Why would you assume that $G$ is abelian? Abelian groups have only linear irreducible characters which is clearly not the case here. Hint: apply orthogonality relations of irreducible characters!

Comment: @NickyHekster Ahh, I forgot to actually read through the attempt. Given that, it would seem that the asker may have stumbled upon a question they do not have anywhere near the prerequisites for yet.

Comment: @NickyHekster I did not think I was implying that G was abelian. Inverse of $a+b$ is $-b -a$, that is not assuming commutativity as far as I know. But I also agree with Tobias Kildetoft, I seem to not have all the background yet for this kind of question. But that is why I am asking here. Thanks.

Comment: @NickyHekster Now I am seeing that "additive group" implies commutativity. I was not trying to imply commutativity, just wanted to use the addition signs and familiar characters from additive groups.

Comment: @jeffery_de_wind OK understood! I can recommend studying representation theory of groups and character theory. A beautiful subject that mixes group theory, linear algebra, Galois theory and algebraic number theory, to name a few.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that an Abelian group must have all of its irreducible characters of degree 1 and therefore you ***may not assume $G$ is additive*** since $\chi_3(C_1) =2,$ $ \chi_4(C_1) = 3,$ and $ \chi_5(C_1) = 3$ are respectively the degrees (dimensions of the vector spaces) corresponding to the $3^{rd},$ $4^{th},$ and $5^{th}$ irreducible representations respectively. This is because $C_1$ is the conjugacy class of the identity element and therefore $\rho(e) = \text{trace}(I_{\text{deg}(\rho) \times \text{deg}(\rho)}) = \text{deg}(\rho) = \text{dim}(V)  $, where $\rho: G \longrightarrow V$ is a representation and $I_{k \times k}$ is the ${k \times k}$ identity matrix, see [chapter 2 of Fulton & Harris](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Representation_Theory/6TwmBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover) or [chapter 2 of Serre](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Linear_Representations_of_Finite_Groups/9mT1BwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover) or even the [wikipedia article on character tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_table). However using the [Shur orthoganility relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_orthogonality_relations) we know that 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i}\chi_{i}(C_k)\chi_{i}(C_3) = 0
\end{equation}
if $k \neq 3$ and therefore choosing say $k=1$ we get that 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i}\chi_{i}(C_1)\chi_{i}(C_3) = 1\cdot 1 + 1\cdot 1 + 2\cdot 2 + 3\cdot (-1)+3\cdot A = 1 + 1 + 4 - 3+ 3 A =0
\end{equation}
and solving for $A$ we get that 
\begin{equation}
A = \frac{-1}{3}(1+1+4-3) = -1.
\end{equation}